# How to unit test my-sql database routes in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, express, mocking

I am trying to unit test my nodejs rest api but due to the fact almost all my routes are calls to my my-sql database, I am finding it very difficult. I have been looking at possibly mocking or stubbing my database but I have had little success (Have tried using Sinon). I definitely don't want to make real calls to the database in the tests so I feel stubbing / mocking is my only option as I don't see any documentation on setting up a test my-sql database in the npm my-sql docs.

My database is in a seperate server.js file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

function getConnection() {
    return pool
}

module.exports = {
    connection: getConnection
}

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    port: 3306,
    multipleStatements: true,
})
```

My main app.js file handles all the routes:

```
const authentication = require('./routes/authentication.js')
const classes = require('./routes/class.js')
const cloudAnchors = require('./routes/cloudAnchors.js')
const assignments = require('./routes/assignments.js')
const assignmentSubmission = require('./routes/assignmentSubmission.js')
const models = require('./routes/models.js')
const webAppAuth = require('./routes/webAppAuth.js')

app.use(authentication)
app.use(classes)
app.use(cloudAnchors)
app.use(assignments)
app.use(assignmentSubmission)
app.use(models)
app.use(webAppAuth)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Responding to root route")
    res.send("This is the root route...")
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3003
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is up and running...")
})
```

If we take authentivation.js for example, it contains a route as follows and exports the router to app.js for use:

```
router.post('/registerTeacher', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Trying to register a new teacher...")

    const email = req.body.email
    const type = req.body.type
    const name = req.body.name
    const hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(req.body.password)
    console.log(hashedPassword)

    const queryString = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); INSERT INTO teacher (userId) VALUES (last_insert_id());"
    server.connection().query(queryString, [name, email, hashedPassword, type], (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to insert new student: " + err)
        res.send({
          "code":500,
          "success":"registration failed"
            });
        return
      }
      res.send({
        "code":200,
        "success":"registration sucessfull",
          });
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

I am wondering how I would best deal with the database to be able to test the routes individually. I am happy to call the route, return dummy response from the mocked/stubbed database and check it but I am just struggling to figure out how to implement it. There appears to be a lot more information on stubbing / mocking mongoose databases but I haven't found any of the content useful.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Is creating a mini-MySQL instance as the test user feasible? Or running mysql as a docker container and putting test data there? It looks like stubbing will remove a lot of the usefulness of testing your application.

Comment: @danblack Looking last night, I came across this piece of code

`process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'`

I am currently running my application locally, would you think it could be an option to just export my database's current schema to a test database and then point to the test database when in test ENV? I would still need to figure out how to do it but would you think this would be adaquate testing?

Comment: Adequate is your call. Sound like a good plan though.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with the same issue and the best solution I thought is to make an integration test.
Basically, here there is no logic to test (otherwise you simply would put the logic outside the router and make unit test of that specific functions), so the point is testing that the data returned by the router is the one you actually expect.

How to do that? With integration test (IT).

Based on my knowledge and experience, I create a docker container with the image of my DB (MySql in my case), create the table, populate the table with some custom data. This data is the one that I expected as output of the router request.

Then run the docker container, configure your IT test context in such a way that it points to your local database and then create your own test. It should call the router and make assertions about the results.

Hope it could be useful for someone in the future.